# Vaadin 14 - Closing IFrame after request from an other application

Tags: vaadin, server-push

In my application, I open an IFrame in one of my views, to access an application through that, and after the process is done in that application, it sends me a request to my callback servlet, after that I want to close this IFrame in my Vaadin application.

Currently I use a BroadCaster in my Servlet, to send events to my view, I receive those events and close the IFrame but I don't see the changes on my window.

I have asyncSupported enabled on my Servlet and @Push annotation on my MainView, which contains my IFrame.

What else I need for this to work?

Comment: One thing you could test to help locate where the problem is would be to have something like a simple button with a listener that shows a notification. If the problem is that changes are not eagerly pushed out, then clicking that button should cause things to get in sync and in that case the problem is related to the `@Push` functionality. If clicking the button has no effect, then it might be something with how the broadcaster events are delivered to the right UI.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Pushmode to Manual and using push() on that view after the changes worked, not sure why automatic wasn't working for me.